# O que ocorre quando eu declaro estar utilizando (using) um namespace numa classe?

Tags: c#, .net, namespace

Quando eu declaro a utilização de um namespace (exemplo: using System;) num arquivo cs (C#), o que ocorre? Estou apenas colocando no escopo da classe as classes pertencentes ao namespace? Não há nada mais? Algo físico, memória, etc?

Comment: Estes são os meus 10 centavos sobre o assunto: Não remover um using desnecessario apenas tem o incoveniente de ter um informação desnecessaria no seu codigo, por um outro lado referencias não utilizadas tem um impacto negativo,

Comment: Namespace e using são recursos para programador, não existe nada físico, desempenho, memória, etc. A thread citada tem uma resposta do bigown que aborda isso.